# In the zsh shell, why can't I pass multiple arguments to a positional parameter?

Tags: zsh, macos-big-sur

I've recently started learning C++. I've been using clang in the zsh shell to compile my code.
For this, I use the same command every time, so I made it into a .zsh file to streamline the process a little.

The code in my file is this:

`clang++ $1 -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -o $2`

It works fine for individual .cpp files; ie if I pass it `file.cpp output`, it works exactly as I want it to. However, if I pass it multiple files, clang complains (it says that the path is not valid).

If I type the following, clang does exactly as I want, and it compiles the multiple files into a UNIX executable named "test".

`clang++ multiple.cpp add.cpp input.cpp -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -o test`

But, if I type the following, it complains. I've also tried escaping spaces and it hasn't worked.

`zsh ../comp.zsh 'multiple.cpp add.cpp input.cpp' attempt`

I don't understand why this isn't working and couldn't find any answers elsewhere. I'm very unfamiliar with zsh.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `'multiple.cpp add.cpp input.cpp'` because this is quoted, it is ONE argument which contains space characters, not multiple arguments separated by spaces.

Comment: I'm not a zsh user but I'm guessing `multiple.cpp add.cpp input.cpp` will be passed to clang++ as a single command line argument?

Comment: I suggest you learn about `make` or similar tools.

Comment: @G.M. Correct; by default, `zsh` does *not* perform word-splitting on unquoted parameter expansions, contrary to the POSIX specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) and [G.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m) saying that `multiple.cpp add.cpp input.cpp` was being passed to clang++ as a single argument.

I changed my code to:
`clang++ $@[0,-2] -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -o $@[-1]`, such that all parameters except for the last are passed individually to clang++ as input files, and the last parameter is passed as the output file.

Comment: You can also use `${=1}` instead of `$@[0,-2]` to force the value to be split on whitespace.

Comment: Thanks this was very useful!